# How to import other list of friends from other group on php?

Tags: php

I'm trying to show on the view page all of the members that are connected with the user. It's something like this `View`:

```
<div class="row form-group" style="padding-left: 50px;">
     <?php $i=0 ?>
     @foreach( $friends as $friend )
        <?php $member = Extras::getUserInfo($friend->user_id); $i++; ?>
        @if ( Auth::user()->user_id != $member->user_id )
        <input type="checkbox" id="cb{{$i}}" value="{{ $member->user_id }}" name="mem[]">
        <label class="col-md-5 boxed" for="cb{{$i}}">
          <p>{{isset($member->first_name) ? $member->first_name: '' ." ". isset($member->last_name) ? $member->last_name: ''}}</p>
             {{isset($member->email) ? $member->email: ''}}
        </label>
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        @endif
     @endforeach
</div>
```

While I'm using this `controller`. It's not my code so I don't really know how to use them.

```
public function showFriends($account, $group) {
        $gdata = \App\Group::where('alias', 'LIKE', $group)->get();
        $group = $gdata[0];
        $event_group = \App\EventGroup::find(EUser::getEUserEGroupID(Auth::user()->user_id, $group->group_id));
        $friends = '';
        if ( $event_group) {
            $friends = EventGroupMembers::where('eg_id', '=', $event_group->eg_id)->get();
        }
    }
```

This is the `getEUserEGroupID`

```
public function getEUserEGroupID($user_id, $gid){
        $egs = \App\EventGroup::where('group_id', '=', $gid)->get();
        if($egs->count() > 0){
            foreach ($egs as $eg){
                $data = \App\EventGroupMembers::where("user_id", "=", $user_id)->where("eg_id", "=", $eg->eg_id)->get();
                if($data->count() > 0){
                    return $data[0]->eg_id;
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: The problem is in your getUserEGroupID. It only takes the group and it members

Comment: Yes but how? Thank you very btw